# Calculating distance then finding people within specific range of given latitude and longitude in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

1. I'm calculating distance between people like below:

```sql
select (
  point(
    (select latlng from user_account where name = 'Manel')
  ) 
<@> 
  point(
    (select latlng from user_account where name = 'Ben')
  )
) as distance
```

which will then output like this:

[image]

2. The scenario is that if Manel wants to get all the people within 5 km, how to write the SQL Query?

(We are using `name` as the input parameter and there is Latlng stored in the table the type is `point`)

[image]

---

#### Here is the sample data:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "user_account";
DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS user_account_id_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE user_account_id_seq INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 START 1 CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE "public"."user_account" (
    "id" integer DEFAULT nextval('user_account_id_seq') NOT NULL,
    "first_name" character varying(64) NOT NULL,
    "last_name" character varying(64) NOT NULL,
    "nickname" character varying(64),
    "age" character varying(32),
    "details" text,
    "email" character varying(128),
    "last_login_time" timestamp,
    "create_time" timestamp,
    "popularity" numeric(5,2),
    "interested_in_relation" character varying(32),
    "interested_in_gender" character varying(32),
    "tag" character varying(256),
    "point" integer,
    "membership_type" character varying(32),
    "account_status" character varying(32),
    "account_name" character varying(32),
    "password" character varying(32),
    "latlng" point,
    CONSTRAINT "user_account_ak_1" UNIQUE ("email"),
    CONSTRAINT "user_account_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) WITH (oids = false);

INSERT INTO "user_account" ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "nickname", "age", "details", "email", "last_login_time", "create_time", "popularity", "interested_in_relation", "interested_in_gender", "tag", "point", "membership_type", "account_status", "account_name", "password", "latlng") VALUES
(8, 'Addison',  'Davies',   'Addison Davies',   NULL,   NULL,   'addison.davies@example.com',   '2021-04-15 15:18:01.982',  '2021-04-15 15:18:01.982',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'blackswan592', 'ajax', '(-0.1277,51.5073)'),
(10,    'Manel',    'Almeida',  'Manel Almeida',    NULL,   NULL,   'manel.almeida@example.com',    '2021-04-15 15:28:25.85',   '2021-04-15 15:28:25.85',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'orangekoala363',   'clarissa', '(-73.5959,-50.4127)'),
(11,    'Ben',  'Tidemann', 'Ben Tidemann', NULL,   NULL,   'ben.tidemann@example.com', '2021-04-15 15:28:37.776',  '2021-04-15 15:28:37.776',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'sadfrog539',   'morpheus', '(51.8397,-147.6034)'),
(12,    'Dieter',   'Campos',   'Dieter Campos',    NULL,   NULL,   'dieter.campos@example.com',    '2021-04-15 15:28:38.939',  '2021-04-15 15:28:38.939',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'silvercat262', 'irish',    '(-72.8698,-139.8647)'),
(13,    'Girão',    'Martins',  'Girão Martins',    NULL,   NULL,   'girao.martins@example.com',    '2021-04-15 15:33:58.464',  '2021-04-15 15:33:58.464',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'yellowgoose254',   'shotgun',  '(-69.7453,-170.808)'),
(14,    'Tammy',    'Hale', 'Tammy Hale',   NULL,   NULL,   'tammy.hale@example.com',   '2021-04-15 15:33:59.925',  '2021-04-15 15:33:59.925',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'beautifulzebra663',    'james007', '(25.8726,55.214)'),
(15,    'Hudson',   'Miller',   'Hudson Miller',    NULL,   NULL,   'hudson.miller@example.com',    '2021-04-15 15:34:33.501',  '2021-04-15 15:34:33.501',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'angrygorilla353',  '414141',   '(-59.3342,-90.5217)'),
(16,    'Apolline', 'Renard',   'Apolline Renard',  NULL,   NULL,   'apolline.renard@example.com',  '2021-04-15 15:35:02.523',  '2021-04-15 15:35:02.523',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'smallleopard612',  '143143',   '(0.6492,18.2443)'),
(17,    'Afet', 'Demirel',  'Afet Demirel', NULL,   NULL,   'afet.demirel@example.com', '2021-04-15 15:35:08.072',  '2021-04-15 15:35:08.072',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'happyfrog105', 'niners',   '(75.6424,138.3762)'),
(18,    'Necati',   'Numanoğlu',    'Necati Numanoğlu', NULL,   NULL,   'necati.numanoglu@example.com', '2021-04-15 15:35:09.242',  '2021-04-15 15:35:09.242',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'bluefish441',  'beavis',   '(70.8946,-7.5597)'),
(19,    'Danny',    'Soto', 'Danny Soto',   NULL,   NULL,   'danny.soto@example.com',   '2021-04-15 15:35:10.32',   '2021-04-15 15:35:10.32',   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'blackpanda305',    'pentium',  '(-79.9498,-171.0615)'),
(20,    'Jesse',    'Aro',  'Jesse Aro',    NULL,   NULL,   'jesse.aro@example.com',    '2021-04-15 15:35:11.457',  '2021-04-15 15:35:11.457',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'beautifulkoala522',    'lonely',   '(-7.8552,-1.1386)'),
(21,    'Lucy', 'Zhang',    'Lucy Zhang',   NULL,   NULL,   'lucy.zhang@example.com',   '2021-04-15 15:35:12.406',  '2021-04-15 15:35:12.406',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'brownladybug716',  'beautiful',    '(63.4473,52.2642)'),
(22,    'محیا', 'گلشن', 'محیا گلشن',    NULL,   NULL,   'mhy.glshn@example.com',    '2021-04-15 15:35:13.503',  '2021-04-15 15:35:13.503',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'browncat969',  'jorge',    '(28.8925,109.2892)'),
(23,    'Jorge',    'Roman',    'Jorge Roman',  NULL,   NULL,   'jorge.roman@example.com',  '2021-04-15 16:20:55.996',  '2021-04-15 16:20:55.996',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'crazyostrich244',  'yyyyyyyy', '(-20.7278,-17.5191)'),
(24,    'Clayton',  'Jacobs',   'Clayton Jacobs',   NULL,   NULL,   'clayton.jacobs@example.com',   '2021-04-15 16:20:57.276',  '2021-04-15 16:20:57.276',  NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   NULL,   0,  'normal',   'active',   'happyrabbit978',   'killers',  '(88.5666,-97.9353)');
```

Comment: Whilst I'm not a PostgreSQL man myself, a quick search indicates that it has a handful of geo-distance functions (as to most of the commerical RDBMS systems).  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/earthdistance.html.  This should be suitable (depending on your version, of course, and whether the functionality is available to you - hopefully it is!)

Comment: Yes, it's nice. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query that returns all the people within a range of 5 km for a given name:

```sql
    SELECT 
        ua1.id AS id1, 
        ua1.first_name AS name1,
        ua1.latlng AS latlng1,
        ua2.id AS id2, 
        ua2.first_name AS name2,
        ua2.latlng AS latlng2, 
        (ua1.latlng <@> ua2.latlng) * 1.609344 as distance
    FROM user_account ua1
    JOIN user_account ua2 ON ua1.id <> ua2.id
    WHERE ua1.first_name = 'Manel'
    AND (ua1.latlng <@> ua2.latlng) * 1.609344 < 5;
```

Please note that the `<@>` operator returns miles instead of kilometers, so additional conversion is necessary, as shown above.

Comment: Hey, do you know, should I add some index or how to speed up the distance search?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Karol's nice answer! I also come up with a solution.

```sql
WITH latlng1 AS (
  SELECT 
    latlng 
  FROM 
    user_account 
  WHERE 
    first_name = 'Manel'
), 
result AS (
  SELECT 
    (
      point(
        (latlng1.latlng)
      ) <@> point(
        (user_account.latlng)
      )
    ) as distance, 
    user_account.nickname 
  from 
    user_account, 
    latlng1
) 
select 
  * 
from 
  result 
where 
  distance < 5 / 1.609344 AND nickname <> 'Manel Almeida'
```